# JS: Erroneous popstate event when trying to navigate back past the initial page load

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I'm trying to implement JS history using pushState/popState. Navigating back and forward works just fine, but I have trouble navigating before the initial page load using the browser's back button. It needs 1 extra hit on the browser's back button to leave the page. Why is that?

```
function action(text) {
  history.pushState({"text":text}, text);
  doAction(text);
}

function doAction(text) {
  $('span').text(text);
}

var $button = $('button');
var $p = $('p');

$p.hide();

action("foo");
$button.on('click', function(){
  action("bar");
  $button.hide();
  $p.show();
})

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
  if (e.state !== null) {
      $button.show();
      $p.text("Next back should navigate away from this page");
  } else {
      $p.text("Still here? Why is that? Next back will really navigate away");
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lilalinux/p8ewyjr9/20/

Edit: Tested with Chrome OS/X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial page load shouldn't use `history.pushState` because it would **add** another history entry. There is alredy an implicit first history item with state `null`.

Using `history.replaceState` for the initial page load, **sets** a state for that item but doesn't add another one.

```
var initialPageLoad = true;
function action(text) {
  if (initialPageLoad) {
    // replace the state of the first (implicit) item
    history.replaceState({"text":text}, text);
  } else {
    // add new history item
    history.pushState({"text":text}, text);
  }
  initialPageLoad = false;
  doAction(text);
}

function doAction(text) {
  $('span').text(text);
}

var $button = $('button');
var $p = $('p');

$p.hide();

action("foo");
$button.on('click', function(){
  action("bar");
  $button.hide();
  $p.show();
})

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
  if (e.state !== null) {
      $button.show();
      $p.text("Next back should navigate away from this page");
//  } else {
// won't happen anymore, as the first item has state now
//      $p.text("Still here? Why is that? Next back will really navigate away");
  }
});
```